# Calculate CPU cycles and its handling bits per second

Tags: cpu

I've wondered about the amount of bits that a given CPU can handles and how should I manage to calculate this specific value.

I wanted to make sure that my thought and also my calculation are right.

Given that I have 64 bit CPU which feature 2.3 Ghz. The amount of bits that being handled per second should be the following :

```
(2.3 * 10^9) * 64
```

Is it that simple or I need consider any other variables?

Comment: What action is the CPU performing on these bits during your performance test?

Comment: is it relevent? i asks in general sir, computing aritmetic for ex.

Comment: What does it mean to "handle a bit"? Handle it how?

Comment: handle on bits of memory which holds program variables types ...

Answer (score 0):

Calculating throughput of a CPU is not as simple. Modern CPUs are pipelined and can execute multiple instructions concurrently if there are no data dependencies, yielding instructions per cycle (IPC) > 1. Some instructions may also have a higher latency than one cycle, meaning IPC can be < 1.
For some operations they might be constrained by memory bandwidth.
And then there are SIMD instructions which can process more data per instruction than the width of a single general purpose register.

- http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining